# как решить эту ошибку с pip?

Tags: pip, python-3.9

когда я пытаюсь установить какую либо библиотеку через pip,(в частности aiogram) выскакивает такая ошибка:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module> load_entry_point('pip==21.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')() File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point return ep.load() File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load return self.resolve() File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0) File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from typing import List, Optional ImportError: No module named typing`

Comment: Вы явно используете Python 2.7, а надо хотя бы 3.7

Comment: нет, я использую именно 3 версию. Почему вы так считаете?

Comment: Потому что в тексте ошибки так написано